# Understanding the role of Partitioning in Riemann Sums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Definition: A partition of the interval $[a, b]$ is a **finite** collection of points in $[a, b]$, one of which is $a$ and one of which is $b$. The points in a partition can be numbered $t_0, ...., t_n$ such that $a = t_0 <t_1 < ... < t_{n-1} < t_n =b$.

I've quoted the above definition of a partition for a reason, as you will see soon. From the definition of a partition, with $P = \{t_0, t_1, ... , t_n{-1}, t_n \}$ we can define the lower and upper Riemann Sums like so:

$$L(f, P) := \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i(t_i - t_{i-1})$$
$$U(f, P) := \sum_{i=1}^{n}M_i(t_i - t_{i-1})$$
where
$$m_i = \inf\{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\}$$
$$M_i = \sup\{f(x): t_{i-1} \leq x \leq t_i\}$$

So essentially what the partition is doing, is selecting *sampling points* to break up the real field over the interval $[a, b]$ into $n$ sub-intervals, $[t_0, t_1],\  [t_1, t_2],\  ...\ , \ [t_{n-2}, t_{n-1}], \ [t_{n-1}, t_{n}]$, correct?

Is is then mathematically correct to rewrite $m_i$ and $M_i$ as the following:

$$m_i = \inf\{f(x): x \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$$
$$M_i = \sup\{f(x): x \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]\}$$

where $[t_{i-1}, t_i] \subset \mathbb{R}$. (and where $[t_{i-1}, t_i]$ is a continuous interval)?

And if $f$ is assumed to be continuous, then $m_i = \min\{f(x) : x \in [t_{i-1}, t_{i}]\}$, and $M_i = \max\{f(x) : x \in [t_{i-1}, t_{i}]\}$ (in words: $m_i$ will be the minimum value $f$ takes on over the $n$ sub-intervals and $M_i$ will be the maximum value $f$ takes on over the $n$ sub-intervals)?

If what I've said above is correct, just out of curiosity why is the $a \leq x \leq b$ notation preferred over the interval notation $x \in [a, b]$?

---

I really do apologize if what I'm writing is blatantly obvious, I asked a question earlier, and I think only now I realized that what the partition was doing, was just selecting sampling points to break up the real field into sub-intervals.

Comment: Everything you've said seems fine from what I can tell (in a first read-through, at least). As for why inequality conditions rather than membership conditions are preferred, I don't really know, but perhaps the inequality notation is considered "more elementary" (don't have to know interval notation) or perhaps it's historical inertia (before the 1950s set-theoretic language and symbols were not used as much). It also might just be the selection of books you've been looking at, although I would guess that you're correct regarding inequality notation being used more often.

Comment: Regarding the "selecting sampling points" idea, you might find the discussion of average value of a function in [these notes](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/qlfang/class_home/Lesson8.pdf) illuminating (the discussion starts on p. 8 of the notes).

Comment: @Dave L.Renfro: you're right, it's really illuminating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *definition* 
$$[x_i,x_{i+1}]=\{ x\in\Bbb R : x_i\leq x\leq x_{i+1}\}$$

So everything you wrote is correct (including your idea of "sampling" and your last question: if $f$ is continuous, $m_i$ is the $\min$ of $f$ over $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ and $M_i$ is the $\max$).

The choice between the notations $x\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ and $x_i\leq x\leq x_{i+1}$ is only a matter of taste.